# Utility for notifying a user that their roaming profile is getting too large to copy before shutdown?

Tags: windows, roaming-profile

My users are having an issue with their roaming profiles getting too large and then their roaming profile is lost.  I believe this is because this is because they are storing too much in their roaming profiles.  Is there a program that can be installed in Windows, that will:

1. Listen for a logoff event
2. Check the size of their Roaming Profile against a size limit I set...
3. If the roaming profile is too big, it will notify the user that they have to decrease the size of the profile.

Does a program like this exist or does it need to written?

Comment: What makes you think it's because they are "too big"?  What related events/errors are being logged?  Windows should wait until the profile is copied (or gets an error) before shutting down. As-is, this is basically a shopping request, which is off-topic.

Comment: Well one of them was 125GB might that have been a little too big?  Ah what sorts of errors should I be looking for in the Event logger?  There's lots of types in there.

Comment: Ones related to the roaming profiles, network drops, etc. try looking at the ones happening around the time that you suspect the problem is occurring.   But, yeah that's a stupid huge profile.

Comment: Is there an info event that will list the time when the system first begins logging off?

Comment: IMO, you're approaching this wrong, see my answer.  GP is your friend. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Group Policy provides ways to deal with profile sizes.

To start, check out `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\User Profiles\Limit profile size`:

> This policy setting sets the maximum size of each user profile and
>   determines the system's response when a user profile reaches the
>   maximum size. This policy setting affects both local and roaming
>   profiles.